# Value error in if else statement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements

I am trying to do the following but getting Value error

```
    if ((df['Session']==1) & (df['Channel']>=1)):
         df['TAG']='FIRST'
    else:
         df['TAG']='OTHERS'
```

Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1]],
                  columns=['Session', 'Channel']
                  )

def conditions(s):
    if (s['Session']==1) and (s['Channel']>=1):
        return 'FIRST'
    else:
        return 'OTHERS'


df['TAG'] = df.apply(conditions, axis=1)
print(df)